# If $F$ is a finite field of size $q=p^n$ and $b\in K$ is algebraic over $F$ then $b^{q^{m}} = b$ for some $m > 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I want to apply a similar type of argument to show that $\alpha^{q} = \alpha$ for all $\alpha\in F$.  When we know that the characteristic of $F$ is $p$ and $|F| = q = p^{n}$.  But I dont know how to incorporate the condition that $b\in K$ is algebraic over $F$.  I know there is some $f\in F[t]$ such that $f(b) = 0$.  Also, $F(b)/F$ is finite... I don't know how to proceed. Any suggestions?

Comment: If $b$ is algebraic over $F$, then $F(b)/F$ is finite.  What do we know about all finite extensions of the field of $q$ elements?  Hint: they are all splitting fields of polynomials of a similar form.

Comment: Thanks let me ponder about this for a moment.

Comment: $f = t^{q^{m}} - t$?

Comment: Yep.  That's it.  All elements in $F(b)$, including $b$, satisfy $t^{q^m}-t$ for some $m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b=0$ then you're done. Otherwise it is a unit and the multiplicative order of a unit $b$ in the group of units divides the order of said group. Given that $F(b)$ is a vector space over a field of size $q$, we find that $|F(b)|=q^m$ for $m=\dim_{\,F}F(b)$. What is the size of the group of units in $F(b)$ then?

Comment: $F(b)^{\times} = q^{m} - 1$

Comment: @geo.ramir3z Right, so $b^{q^m-1}=1$. Multiply by $b$ and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, this was the type of argument I thought would work originally just got stuck.